# General solution to multivariable discrete-time linear model with complex eigenvalues from Otto & Day (2007)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

In Otto & Day's (2007) *A Biologist's Guide to Mathematical Modelling*, they give the general solution to discrete-time linear models as:

$\vec{n(t)} = \boldsymbol{A D^t A^{-1}}\vec{n(0)}$

where $\vec{n(t)}$ is a vector of solutions at time $t$ for the $d$ variables in the system, $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a $d \times d$ matrix of column-wise right eigenvectors, and $D^t$ is a $d \times d$ diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

For the system with matrix of coefficients $\boldsymbol{M} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$, the complex eigenvalues are:

$\vec{\lambda} = \frac{a + d \pm \sqrt{ - (a-d)^2 - 4bc}}{2}$

which can be written as $\lambda_{1} = \alpha + \beta i = R(\cos(\beta t) + i \sin(\beta t))$
giving:

$\boldsymbol{D}^t = 
\begin{bmatrix}
R(\cos(\theta t) + i\sin(\theta t)) & 0 \\
\ & R(\cos(\theta t) - i \sin(\theta t))
\end{bmatrix}$

The matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is:

$
\boldsymbol{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-a + d + \sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc} & -a + d - \sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}
\end{bmatrix}
$

Otto and Day multiply out $\boldsymbol{A D^t A^{-1}}$ to get:

$
R^t 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta t) + \frac{a-d}{2 \beta}sin(\theta t) & \frac{b}{\beta} \sin(\theta t) \\
\frac{c}{\beta}\sin(\theta t) & \cos(\theta t) - \frac{a-d}{2 \beta} \sin(\theta t)
\end{bmatrix}
$

**My problem is that I am struggling to multiply out the matrices to get their result.**

From the definitions of $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}^t$, I first derived $\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}$ as:

$
\boldsymbol{A^{-1}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a - d + \sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}}{2\sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}} &
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-(a-d}^2 - 4bc} \\
\frac{-a + d + \sqrt{-(a-d)^2- 4bc}}{2\sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}} & 
\frac{1}{-\sqrt{-(a-d}^2 - 4bc}
\end{bmatrix}
$

I then find $\boldsymbol{AD}$ as:

$
\boldsymbol{AD} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
R(\cos(\theta t) + i\sin(\theta t)) & R(\cos(\theta t) - i\sin(\theta t)) \\
\frac{(-a+d+\sqrt{-(a-d)^2 + 4bc})R(\cos(\theta t) + i\sin(\theta t)}{2} & 
\frac{(-a+d-\sqrt{-(a-d)^2 + 4bc})R(\cos(\theta t) - i\sin(\theta t)}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$

But then multiplying by $\boldsymbol{A^{-1}}$ does not give me the desired answer. To save space, I'll take the first element of $\boldsymbol{A D^{1} A^{-1}}$:

$\boldsymbol{(A D^{1} A^{-1}})_{11} = R(\cos(\theta t) + i\sin(\theta t))\frac{a - d + \sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}}{2\sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}} + R(\cos(\theta t) - i\sin(\theta t))\frac{-a + d + \sqrt{-(a-d)^2- 4bc}}{2\sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}}\\
= \frac{R}{\sqrt{-(a-d)^2 - 4bc}}\big[(\sqrt{(a-d)^2 - 4bc}) \cos(\theta t) + (i)\sin(\theta t)(a - d)\big] $

I am now unsure how they Otto and Day got the first element of their solution. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Use `\sin,\cos,\tan,\cot, \arcsin,\ln,\det,\gcd`...